# How do I refer to a widet's id outside of that widget's root class?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

This question has been answered before but in terms that I find hard to understand.

What I'm trying to do is get the `item` from the `<SecondWindow>`'s `TextInput` and use that in `<CustomPopup>`'s `Item:` label. I have two files: the python file and the kv file. How would I do this? Please explain in terms a beginner can understand.
Python file:

```
import kivy
#kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
#from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import csv

class WelcomeWindow(Screen):
    pass

class AnymoreWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass
    #manager = ObjectProperty(None)

class SecondWindow(Screen):  
    def open(self):
        open_popup()
 
def open_popup():
    CustomPopup().open()

#kv = Builder.load_file('vercluse.kv')

class VercluseApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VercluseApp().run()
```

kv file (shortened for comprehension):

```
<CustomPopup>:
    title: 'Are you sure?'
    auto_dismiss: False
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    size_hint: .75, .75
    BoxLayout:
        GridLayout:   
            cols: 2
            
            Label:
                text: 'Item:'
            Label:
                text: 'item id'
            
            Label:
                text: 'Quantity:'
            Label: 
                text: 'Quantity id'
            
            Label:
                text: 'Unit Price:'
            Label:
                text: 'unit price id'
            
            Label:
                text: 'Bought at:'
            Label:
                text: 'Location id'
            
            Button:
                text: 'Go Back'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: 'Confirm'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
                    app.root.current = 'more'
                    #root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
...
<SecondWindow>:
    
    name: 'second'
    item: item
    amount: amount
    price: price
    location: location
    date: date
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: 'What item did you buy?'
            TextInput:
                id: item
           
            Label:
                text: 'How many of the item did you buy?'
            TextInput:
                id: amount
            
            Label:
                text: """What's the price of each item?"""
            TextInput:
                id: price
            
            Label:
                text: 'What site or store did you purchase the item from?'
            TextInput:
                id: location
            
            Label:
                text: 'What date did you purchase the item?'
            TextInput:
                id: date
                hint_text: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, .20
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.0
                text: 'Back'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "welcome"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
            Button:
                size_hint: 0.5, 1.0
                pos_hint: {'right': 1.0}
                text: 'Next'
                on_release:
                    root.open()
```

I'm seriously struggling with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv`, change:

```
        Label:
            text: 'item id'
```

to:

```
        Label:
            text: app.root.ids.item.text
```

This assumes that `SecondWindow` is the root class of your `App`. You haven't provided enough information to determine the structure of your GUI, but it is likely that you are using a `ScreenManager` as the root. If that is true, then those lines become:

```
        Label:
            text: app.root.get_screen('second').ids.item.text
```

Comment: You, Mr. Anderson, are a lifesaver. Words cannot express how thankful I am. What a simple solution, too.